# REGEX (regular expression) Replace <i> tags with <span> tags for font awesome with

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, wcag

i want to replace with REGULAR EXPRESSIONS anything that starts with

```
<i class="fa
```

and finishes with

```
 ></i>
```

Replace it with this starting as

```
 <span class="fa
```

And finishes with

```
></span>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: <(/?)i\b((?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*)>

this one is for the <i> tab and the </i> keeping the rest inside, i am fine with that

Comment: Please add all attempts to your question by editing it